# Microsoft Graph get users who only have profile picture

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to get users and filter by profile picture? I would like to skip users who are missing image. Or by using query parameters to filter by image dimension

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,GivenName,DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Surname&$top=430
```